# Failure of polymorphism due to inability to resolve template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I know this seems convoluted, but I hope somebody may point out my mistake here. I'm sure the design will leave a bad taste in some of your mouths, and I'm happy to hear design alternatives. But the form comes from modeling in the problem domain.

I'm sure I'm being silly, but there is something about the way templates couple with inheritance that is confusing me. Here is some pared down code with a description to follow:

```
// main.cpp

#include <cstdio>

template <typename POD>
class A {
 public:
  POD data;
  POD get_a() { return data; }
};

template <typename T>
class B {
 public:
  virtual void do_something_with_an_A_child(const T&) = 0;
};

class ADerived : public A<float> {
 public:
  ADerived(float a) { data = a; }
};

class BDerived : public B<ADerived> {
 public:
  virtual void do_something_with_an_A_child(const ADerived& someA) {
    printf("A bit of A-type's data: %f\n", someA.data);
  }
};

template <typename POD>
class Aggregator {
 public:
  A<POD>* instanceOfA;
  B<A<POD>>* instanceOfB;
  Aggregator(A<POD>* anA, B<A<POD>>* aB) : instanceOfA(anA), instanceOfB(aB) {}
};

int main() {
  ADerived myADerived(3.14159f);
  BDerived myBDerived;

  Aggregator<float> myAggregator(&myADerived, &myBDerived);

  return 1;
}
```

So `A` is a class template that's signature is just some built-in type(s). (In my particular case, `A` has methods which operate on its internal data.) The class `B` is meant to promise an interface to some operations that are meant for a specific instance of an `A<.>`. So, in the code above, you see I define `A` and `B` as template classes and then create classes which inherit from those template classes, giving `ADerived` and `BDerived`.

(In the real case, `A` represents a mathematical model and some data, and `B` is an interface to perform a mathematical optimization on a model.)

Now, an class which should have links to instances of an `ADerivded` and `BDerived` (for the purposes of creating a generic algorithm based on their interfaces) I have called `Aggregator`, which simply takes some pointers in the constructor. I only want `Aggregator` to need to know about the `POD` types, since it is meant only to manipulate the interfaces and not worry too much about what the objects contain.

I get the following compiler error from `clang++` with `-std=c++14`:

```
main.cpp:42:21: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Aggregator<float>'
  Aggregator<float> myAggregator(&myADerived, &myBDerived);
                    ^            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:35:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'BDerived *' to 'B<A<float> > *' for 2nd argument
  Aggregator(A<POD>* anA, B<A<POD>>* aB) : instanceOfA(anA), instanceOfB(aB) {}
  ^
```

The meaning is clear, but I'm not sure why it can't see that a `BDerived` is a `B<A<float>>`. I mean, it is specifically a `B<ADerived>`, but `ADerived` is an `A<float>`, and therefore a `BDerived` should be seen as a `B<A<float>>`. This obviously isn't the case, so either I'm doing something stupid and hope to have someone point it out, or this isn't possible in C++, and I need some alternative design suggestions.

Comment: `B<ADerived>` and `B<A<POD>>` are completely different types, it does not matter if `ADerived` is inherited from `A<POD>` or not. Your design does not look right, but it is difficult to suggest anything, there is not enough info

Comment: Suggestion, quite often it is easier to implement what you need for specific type without template and then generalize it.

Comment: Thanks @Slava. Believe it or not, this is an attempt to _lift_ from an algorithm I already coded for specific types. I am trying to generalize my API to a library/framework. It is difficult to get right, and I'm quite sure I'm not. But I guess we all learn somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template arguments are resolved statically and to exact type. Thus `B<ADerived>` won't decay to `B<A<POD>>` even if `ADerived` is a descendant of `A<POD>`. You might work around this by:

- Taking one more template parameter, `T`, in `Aggregator`, and optionally ensuring (using `std::enable_if<>` and `std::is_base<>`) that `A<POD>` is a base of `T`, or
- Exposing `T` in `B` using a `typedef`, then taking `T` in `Aggregator` and storing `T` and `A<B::T>` in `Aggregator`.

Comment: Thanks. You inspired me to the answer I need. I will take the types of the derived classes as template arguments and use `auto` and `decltype(.)` to get the information about return types as I need it. That way, only the original `A` needs to know about the POD types.